# Ways for iPhone and iPad to save webpage as a single HTML file?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, web-browser, html

I’ve been using my MacBook to save the posts from a blog I’ve been reading, and I’ve been doing that by using a plug-in on Firefox that can save the entire webpage into a single HTML page with all the things embedded in the file. **Can an iPhone or iPad do the same thing?**

I know that Safari and some other apps can save the entire webpage into a PDF, but is it possible to save it into a single HTML file? Anyone knows any app or plug-in can do?

Greatly appreciate anyone that could help

Comment: A PDF saves links.

Answer (score 1):

There's built-in features that do this.

### Download linked file

Go to a page where you can see the link of the page you want to save as an html file. Then, long-press the link of the page you want to save as html and select "Download Linked File".

[image]

It will automatically be downloaded somewhere in Files. Open Files and find the file. It should look like this :

[image]

Then, you can open it and it should be the html document.

[image]

### Save page as web archive

You will get a .webarchive file but it is as you're visiting the page (you can click on links, etc.).

For this, click on the Share icon at the bottom of your screen and choose "Options" below the page title.

[image]

Then, select "Web Archive" :

[image]

It will automatically be downloaded somewhere in Files. Open Files and find the file. It should look like this :

[image]

You can open it and see the saved page as if looking at in in-browser (of course, links are openable) :

[image]

<sub>*(Click images to open full size)*</sub>

Comment: I tried your way but it sends it can only save texts but not the pictures. Are there other better ways? Still greatly appreciate your help though I just learned this way today!

Comment: @MicahS.Z. Web archives also saves pictures. I know it's not html, but it looks to me like the description you have made of what you want. I'll maybe come up later today with an edit to my answer with another way.

Comment: I tried the web-archive single file method. I'm not sure which apps can open these  beside quick-view in Files, but that did open the page with images, and the links were intact ready to switch to Safari and open them there. After opening the Share menu there is an Options menu at the top. I switched from Automatic to WebArchive there and then proceeded below to save the page to a destination via Files. I don't know if any other apps can use these besides Files, maybe Safari on iOS or Mac? I'd like to find a shortcut that could save webpages complete in MHTML format!

Comment: @OldUncleHo I think the only way to open these files is quickview in Files as you already noticed. I'm sure there is a way to trigger the action of saving the webpage as a WebArchive with a keyboard shortcut (if you've got an external keyboard). Is this the kind of shortcut you were talking about?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer.  By shortcut I meant using the (very limited) ipad/iphone scripting facility. I believe the scripting is called shortcut language, and the files produced are not really compiled, they're like a limited batch-script.  I've seen some fairly fancy ones, but you're always working within the limitations of what the scripting allows. There are libraries of such scripts which can serve as examples of what is possible and how it can be done. Sometimes it's convenient to create one to batch a few tasks. Now they've added code to respond to some events.

Comment: @OldUncleHo Okay. I'll try to find a way to have that automated with a shortcut. I'll come back to you in a bit. :)